# Logistic regression: use of the term "prediction"

Tags: regression, logistic, prediction, terminology

I would be grateful for any advice on this. I am currently working on an analysis where we are trying to identify what variables would be most useful in predicting a particular binary outcome. We used univariate analyses first to identify associations between the outcome variable and several independent variables in our dataset. We then built a logistic regression model using these variables.

In our paper, we have discussed these variables as "predictor variables" for the outcome status. One of the reviewers has advised that they feel the aim of the study was to identify the variables that are associated with the outcome status and that the term "prediction" should not be used.

We know that the variables had association with the outcome variable from the univariate analysis, but the aim of the logistic regression model was to see whether the variables could be useful in identifying the outcome variable status.

Could someone advise me on why the use of the term "prediction" is not appropriate in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the objection to calling your fitted values "predictions" or your explanatory variables "predictors"? At first I thought the latter and, while I disagree with the logic, can see why the reviewer might want a predictor to have a causal relationship with the outcome. Now I think you mean the former, and that would be quite the review of a regression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context statistical model building, terms *predictor*, *explanatory variable*, *independent variable*, and *input* (among some others) have been used interchangeably. I would not see the use of the term *predictor* as an issue in your case, regardless of whether the aim of your study was to build a descriptive or a predictive model. And because the terms have been used interchangeably, I also think that it won't hurt your paper much, if you simply replace *predictor* with one of the alternative terms.

I do not know if you have already done this in your manuscript, but it would be useful  to assess the predictive accuracy of your model, using, for instance cross-validation. Putting your work very clearly in the predictive landscape should clarify any remaining confusions that the reviewer may have had regarding your use of the term *predictor*.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's very helpful. We are coming up against challenges in getting a dataset that we can use as a validation dataset, as the outcome variable is rare and the data for the independent variables is not commonly collected. I really appreciate the information provided.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: (+1) @user255347 If this answer addresses your question, I'd encourage you to accept and/or upvote it (see the check mark and the up/down arrows beside the answer). Doing so helps the community here by letting us know that your question has been addressed, and also lets future readers know that you found this useful. 

Of course, you're welcome to wait for more answers and also to clarify whether you need more explanation about anything.